# .NET 6 Identity int foreign key cannot target int primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I get this error when I try to add the migration:

> The relationship from 'MyCart.Klienti' to 'Klienti.MyCarts' with foreign key properties {'KlientiId' : int} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship.

Both keys have the same data type - `int` - so I'm not sure where the problem is.

This is my code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyCart>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.CartItemId)
                    .HasName("PK__MyCart__488B0B0A1FDF5DF6");

                entity.ToTable("MyCart");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Food)
                    .WithMany(p => p.MyCarts)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.FoodId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__MyCart__FoodId__4AB81AF0");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Klienti)
                    .WithMany(p => p.MyCarts)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.KlientiId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK__MyCart__KlientiI__49C3F6B7");
            });

modelBuilder.Entity<Klienti>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("Klienti");

                entity.Property(e => e.City)
                    .HasMaxLength(30)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Email)
                    .HasMaxLength(60)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                    .HasMaxLength(20)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Password)
                    .HasMaxLength(30)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.PhoneNumber)
                    .HasMaxLength(15)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Role)
                    .HasMaxLength(10)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.StreetName)
                    .HasMaxLength(40)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Surname)
                    .HasMaxLength(20)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.ZipCode)
                    .HasMaxLength(12)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
            });

public partial class Klienti : IdentityUser
{
    public Klienti()
    {
        MyCarts = new HashSet<MyCart>();
    }

    public int KlientiId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Surname { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Password { get; set; } = null!;
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = null!;
    public string StreetName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string ZipCode { get; set; } = null!;
    public string City { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Role { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<MyCart> MyCarts { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyCart
{
    public int CartItemId { get; set; }
    public int KlientiId { get; set; }
    public int FoodId { get; set; }

    public virtual Food Food { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Klienti Klienti { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: IdentityUser has id of string.  You should not extend that user unless you really need to.  If you need the UserId just get it from the context when they are logged and use in a Klient table/Cart Table.  Don't inherit and this will fix your issue.

Comment: @AliK but i really have to use identity

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: @AliK I need it for creating the registration in my project, unless there is another way of doing it without Identity? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Yes there is.  Leave the user registration process alone.  Allow user to register as normal.  Crate your other table  Klienti and you can use the UserID as reference to the user.  So you don't need to inherit unless you want to specifically change the user table which I don't suggest.  This way you can create many tables as you need and reference UserID from the users table whenever its required.